# AttributeError: module 'torch.distributed' has no attribute 'init_process_group'

Tags: neural-network, deep-learning, pytorch

AttributeError: module 'torch.distributed' has no attribute 'init_process_group'

Still getting this error after installing latest pytorch-nightly and other stuff, when I tried to run the imagenet example script from pytorch/examples.

Steps to reproduce:

1. Go to https://github.com/pytorch/examples/tree/master/imagenet
2. Prepare ImageNet dataset according to the instructions
3. Run main.py with your suitable arguments along with multiple gpus distributed training

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not related to data science but pytorch support

Comment: How do I do that?

Comment: I think you've got two options - you could add in a lot more detail about your installation and your error messages so any pytorch experts here might be able to diagnose the problem. Or you might have more luck on the pytorch support forums and github where people might be more familiar with the script you're referring to.